# Can I use jax-rs with j2ee 1.4

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, jax-rs, websphere

I have a 1.4 EAR deployed on WAS 8.5+.

I've created a JAX-RS RESTful service WAR bundled inside the EAR. Ive got a ton of deployment scripts related to this EAR, so I'd prefer not to deploy the war separately.

When reading docs, it's all about JEE6+ compliance

Has anyone actually done this in the real world?

Comment: What have you tried?  What didn't work?  (This seems like a question for IBM support rather than Stack Overflow.)

Comment: If you are deploying to WAS 8.5, why dont you update your app to JavaEE 6?

Comment: @BrettKail - Originally, I was getting 404s when attempting to access the resources.  I've now had the IHS webserver plugin configured to point at WAS, and I get 500s now.  I am mainly looking to see if someone has actually done this, and that im not barking up an impossible tree.  Its not referenced in documentation. JAX-WS isn't also documented to work with 1.4, but I have that working.

Comment: @Gas - EE6 is not an option.  Way too many old 2.1 EJB that freak out when this is attempted.  I would love to do this if I had resources/time.